# Polya-Burnside coloring question of regular n-gon, detailed explanation

Tags: abstract-algebra, coloring

Say I have a pentagon and I want to color each of its vertices using 2 colors. To apply Burnside theorem, I am letting the dihedral group $D_{10n}$ act and there's a hint saying assign symmetry to each vertex. I would like to know what to do in order to arrive at the expression shown below.

[image: From Rotman's Advanced Modern Algebra]

Comment: What part of Burnside's don't you understand? Do you understand what summation notation is? Do you understand that $|X^g|$ refers to the number of fixed points in $X$ of the action of $g$? Do you know what the elements of the dihedral group are? Have you tried counting the number of fixed point for each of the elements? (My answer categorizes the symmetries into three different types, so you have three fixed point calculations instead of ten. This is standard.) You already know you're supposed to apply Burnside, so *do it*, and if you can't tell us what went wrong or what you don't get!

Comment: This link at [MSE Meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions#13335) has many examples of Polya / Burnside, ranging from the introductory to the advanced, written by different users with various audiences in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Burnside's says the # of orbits equals the average # of fixed points of the symmetries.

The dihedral group of order ten has the trivial action, four rotations of order five, and five different reflections across diagonals. How many fixed points does each type of action have? Average.